# Parse HTML iFrame SRC in PHP with SimpleHTMLDOM

Tags: php, html, dom

This how my HTML looks like :

```
<div class="academy_page">
    <span class="academy_page_header">Academy:</span>
    <div>
        <div class="videopage_block" align="center">
            <iframe class="videopage_video" src="//player.vimeo.com/video/67353453644?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="300" height="150" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
            <div class="academy_text">How to Ride a Skateboard</div>
        </div>
        <div class="videopage_block" align="center">
            <iframe class="videopage_video" src="//player.vimeo.com/video/9435345343?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="300" height="150" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
            <div class="academy_text">How to Build a Skateboard</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

This is how I'm parsing it:

```
foreach($html->find('div.academy_page') as $element){

        foreach($element->find('div.videopage_block') as $dulce) {

            $item['title'] = $dulce->find('div.academy_text', 0)->plaintext;
            $item['vimeo_url'] = $dulce->find('iframe')->src;

            $returnArray[] = $item;
        }
     }
```

This is my result in json:

```
[
  {
    "title": "How to Ride a Skateboard",
    "vimeo_url": null
  },
  {
    "title": "How to Build a Skateboard",
    "vimeo_url": null
  }
]
```

How do I get my iFrame SRC?

I've also tried `$item['vimeo_url'] = $dulce->find('.videopage_video')->plaintext;` and nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can use:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query("//div[@class='videopage_block']") as $node){

    echo $node->getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0]->getAttribute("src");
    echo $node->getElementsByTagName('div')[0]->nodeValue;
}
```

---

**Update:**

To get the video id:

```
$iframe_src = $node->getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0]->getAttribute("src")
$video_id = preg_replace('%.*?video/(\d+)\?.*%i', '$1', $iframe_src);
```

Comment: How do I incorporate this into what I already have? Seems like an easy way to get the src if that's the only thing I needed

Comment: Ok, I'll make some adjustments to my answer, 1''

Comment: Appreciate it Pedro

Comment: Pedro! You're a life saver. This 100% gives me what I needed. One more question, do you know how I can just return the number part of the src? I only need `67353453644` part of  `//player.vimeo.com/video/67353453644?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0`. If you could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it! Marked as answer

Comment: @Walker Please have a look to the updated answer. GL

Answer (score 0):

you can point to the `src` Attribute directly in SimpleHTMLDOM

```
  $iframe = $html->find( 'iframe' , 1 )->src ;
```

Reference [official manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_traverse)